# ng-class does not change class unless I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm using ng-class in my view to change the class of and element and it works fine on page load. Here is my code:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-class="'{{account.currency}}' == '{{currency}}' ? 'active': 'inactive'" ng-repeat="account in accounts" bind="accounts">
    <a href="#/deposits/{{account.currency}}" ng-click="changeClass('{{account.currency}}', '{{currency}}')">
    {{currency}}
    </a>
  </li>
<ul>
```

As you can see, it takes the second currency from the URL and compares it with another to decide which class it should assign to my li element.

The trouble now is that when someone clicks on the link and the URL changes, the class assigned does not change. Any idea how I can get the class assigned by ng-class to change when the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myctrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.accounts = [{
    currency: 'Doller'
  }, {
    currency: 'Pound'
  }, {
    currency: 'Euro'
  }];
  
  vm.changeClass = function(account) {
    vm.active = account.currency;  
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myctrl as ct">
    <ul>
      <li ng-class="{'active': ct.active === account.currency}" ng-repeat="account in ct.accounts">
        <a href="#" ng-click="ct.changeClass(account)">
          {{account.currency}}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm actually failing to modify this to get it to work with my existing code because I had used  a custom directive - My code looks like this:

Comment: Actually it worked. I just replaced vm with scope. Thanks a lot. may the wind always be at in your back.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call a function for this, this can be easily achieved inline

try like this:

```
<li ng-class="{'active' : account.currency == currency, 'inactive': 
account.currency != currency}">
```

OR

```
<li ng-class="{true: 'active', false: 'inactive'}[account.currency == currency]">
```

If you're using angular v.1.1.4+

```
<li ng-class="account.currency == currency ? 'active': 'inactive'}">
```

Comment: Thank you for that tip. I've followed your suggestion and put my code inline. But the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `ng-class= {'active': account.currency === currency}`

in the css file you should have the `.active{}` class. And let the inactive class be the default behaviour.

P.S The answers of Dhaval should work also

Comment: Although this is another alternative that works, it doesn't solve the problem The problem is really that when I click on the link, 'active' class should be removed from the old active element and assigned to the new active element and this does not happen. Is there a way I can also automatically change the class that's on the element when i click on the link?